# DESCARGAR INFORMACION DE PAGINA WEB MEDIANTE MACRO VBA EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba, consultar

Amigos, cordial saludo.
Tengo el siguiente inconveniente para ver si me pueden ayudar:
Quiero extraer una información de una página web; ya logré pasarle los datos al formulario y darle clic al botón consultar y me muestra la información. El problema radica en que el html donde están los datos no tienen el ID y no sé cuál sería la instrucción correcta para descargarla información.

[image: CODIGO]

[image: CODIGO HTML]

Comment: Lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Por favor, lee [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y no olvides leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Visita también el  [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.